# Android Studio terminal with custom working directory

Tags: android, android-studio, intellij-idea, cmd

I'm trying to set the default working directory for the Android Studio "Terminal" tab, but changing the default shell path in the settings to`cmd.exe /k "cd /d c:\android\sdk"` doesn't work: I get the error "Can't Open Local Terminal, couldn't create PTY".

Is it possible to change the Terminal's default working directory within Android Studio?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to wrap `cmd.exe` to `"`:

```
"cmd.exe" /k "cd /d c:\android\sdk"
```

For more info check this [thread of comments](https://blog.jetbrains.com/blog/2016/05/11/security-update-for-intellij-based-ides-v2016-1-and-older-versions/#comment-254189) where they took about the same issue.

Comment: I'm sorry, but this doesn't work. I still get the "java.io.IOException: Couldn't create PTY" error.
I believe the adding the quotes is a solution to custom .exe files.

Comment: @HugoM.Zuleta Check also this **[comment](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-136139#comment=27-1422182)**